# Excel Macro Selects cell a8 no matter what the code says

Tags: excel, vba

I wrote a macro that runs upon opening the file, and ended the macro with range("a1").select.  The problem is no matter what I end the macro with, ie. scroll, select, active, the selected cell is A8 when the file is opened and the macro is finished running.  A8 is directly below a row with cells merged accross several columns, I'm not sure if this is the cause.  Help please!

code:

```
Sub Macro1()

'
    Rows("6:6").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
    Range("B7:O8").Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    Range("B6:H8").Select

    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeLeft)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Weight = xlMedium
        .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeTop)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Weight = xlMedium
        .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Weight = xlMedium
        .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeRight)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Weight = xlMedium
        .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    End With

    Range("B6:H6").Select
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeLeft)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Weight = xlMedium
        .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeTop)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Weight = xlMedium
        .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Weight = xlMedium
        .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeRight)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Weight = xlMedium
        .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    End With

    Range("B7:B8,E7:E8").Select
        With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeTop)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Weight = xlMedium
        .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Weight = xlMedium
        .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeRight)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Weight = xlMedium
        .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    End With
    Range("C7:C8,F7:F8").Select

    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeLeft)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Weight = xlMedium
        .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeTop)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Weight = xlMedium
        .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Weight = xlMedium
        .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeRight)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Weight = xlMedium
        .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    End With

    Range("D7:E7,G7:H7").Select


    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Weight = xlMedium
        .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    End With

    Range("B6").Select
    With Selection.Font
        .Size = 14
    End With
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Current Period"
    Range("B6:H6").Select
    With Selection
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenterAcrossSelection
           End With
    Range("B8").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Actual"
    Range("B8").Select
    With Selection
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter

    End With
    With Selection.Font
        .Name = "Helvetica"
        .Size = 12
    End With
    Range("C8").Select
    With Selection.Font
        .Name = "Helvetica"
        .Size = 12
    End With
    With Selection
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter

    End With
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Budget"
    Rows("8:8").Select
    With Selection
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter

    End With
    Range("D8").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "$"
    Range("E8").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "%"
    Range("D7:E8").Select
    Range("D8").Activate
    With Selection.Font
        .Name = "Helvetica"
        .Size = 10
    End With
    Range("F8").Select
    With Selection.Font
        .Name = "Helvetica"
        .Size = 12
    End With
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Last Year"
    Range("G7:H8").Select
    Range("G8").Activate
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "$"
    With Selection.Font
        .Name = "Helvetica"
        .Size = 10
    End With

    Range("H8").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "%"
    Range("D7").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "B/(W) Than Budget"
    Range("D7:E7").Select
    With Selection
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenterAcrossSelection

    End With
    Range("G7:H7").Select
    With Selection
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenterAcrossSelection

    End With
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "B/(W) Than Last Year"
    Range("B6:H8").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("I6").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Range("I6").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Year To Date"
    Rows("1:4").Select
    With Selection.Font
        .Size = 14
    End With
    Rows("9:138").Select
    With Selection.Font
        .Size = 10
    End With
    Rows("125:125").Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    Rows("133:133").Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    Range("B:D,F:G,I:K,M1,M:N").Select
    Range("M1").Activate
    Selection.ColumnWidth = 15
    Range("E:E,h:h,l:l,o:o").Select
    Selection.ColumnWidth = 12
    Range("A:A").Select
    Selection.ColumnWidth = 40
    With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
        .PrintTitleRows = "$1:$8"
    End With


Rows("6:6").Select
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown


Columns("i:i").Select
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlRight

Range("g14:i14").Select
With Selection
.HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
End With

Range("g14:h14").Select
With Selection
.HorizontalAlignment = xlCenterAcrossSelection
End With
Range("b13:i13").Select
With Selection
.HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
End With

Range("b13:h13").Select
With Selection
.HorizontalAlignment = xlCenterAcrossSelection
End With

Range("k16:k200").Select
Selection.Copy
Range("i16:i200").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats

Range("i:i,q:q").Select
Selection.ColumnWidth = 38
With Selection
.WrapText = True
End With

Range("i13").Select
Selection.Borders(xlEdgeTop).LineStyle = xlNone
    Selection.Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = xlNone


Range("i16").Select
With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Weight = xlHairline
        .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    End With
Range("i17").Select
With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Weight = xlHairline
        .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    End With

Selection.Copy
Range("i17:i200,q16:q200").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste

Range("i14").Select
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeTop)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Weight = xlMedium
        .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    End With
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Describe Variance"
With Selection
.HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
End With
Selection.Offset(1, 0).Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "to CP Budget"
With Selection
.HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
End With
Range("i14:i15").Select
Selection.Copy
Range("q14:q15").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats

Range("q14").Select
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeTop)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Weight = xlMedium
        .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    End With
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Describe Variance"
With Selection
.HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
End With
Selection.Offset(1, 0).Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "to YTD Budget"
With Selection
.HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
End With


Cells.Find("ebitda", lookat:=xlWhole).Select
Selection.Offset(2, 0).Select
Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.Offset(200, 0)).Select
Selection.EntireRow.Delete

Cells.Find("ebitda", lookat:=xlWhole).Select
Selection.Offset(3, 0).Select
ActiveCell = "Explanation of EBITDA Variance to Budget (Only required if variance exceeded the acceptable range for your group)"
Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.Offset(0, 16)).Select
With Selection.Font
        .Size = 14
        .Bold = True
    End With
With Selection
.HorizontalAlignment = xlCenterAcrossSelection
End With
Selection.Offset(1, 0).Select
Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.Offset(0, 16)).Select
Selection.Merge
Selection.RowHeight = 50
With Selection.Font
        .Size = 10
         .Bold = True
    End With


    With Selection
.HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
.VerticalAlignment = xlTop
.WrapText = True
End With
 With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeLeft)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Weight = xlMedium
        .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeTop)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Weight = xlMedium
        .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Weight = xlMedium
        .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeRight)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Weight = xlMedium
        .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    End With

Range("a1:q11").Select
With Selection
.HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
End With

With Selection
.HorizontalAlignment = xlCenterAcrossSelection
End With


Range("a6").Select
ActiveCell = "Publisher's Summary"
With Selection.Font
        .Size = 14
    End With
Range("a9").Select
ActiveCell = "Market Outlook"
With Selection.Font
        .Size = 14
    End With



Rows("10:10").Select
Selection.RowHeight = 70
Range("a10:q10").Select
Selection.Merge
 With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeLeft)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Weight = xlMedium
        .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeTop)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Weight = xlMedium
        .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Weight = xlMedium
        .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeRight)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Weight = xlMedium
        .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    End With
        With Selection
.HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
.VerticalAlignment = xlTop
.WrapText = True
End With

    With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
        .RightHeader = "&9Page &P of &N"
        .LeftMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.25)
        .RightMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.25)
        .TopMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.25)
        .BottomMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.25)
        .HeaderMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.1)
        .FooterMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.15)
        .CenterHorizontally = True
        .Orientation = xlLandscape
        .FitToPagesWide = 1
          .FitToPagesTall = 2
        .Zoom = False
    End With


    ActiveWindow.Zoom = 70


Rows("7:7").Select
Selection.RowHeight = 180
Range("a7:q7").Select
Selection.Merge
 With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeLeft)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Weight = xlMedium
        .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeTop)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Weight = xlMedium
        .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Weight = xlMedium
        .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeRight)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Weight = xlMedium
        .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    End With
    With Selection
.HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
.VerticalAlignment = xlTop
.WrapText = True
End With

'

Cells.Select

With Selection

.Locked = False
End With

Cells.Find("ebitda", lookat:=xlWhole).Select
Selection.Offset(1, 1).Select

Range(ActiveCell, "h13").Select

With Selection

.Locked = True
End With

Cells.Find("ebitda", lookat:=xlWhole).Select
Selection.Offset(1, 9).Select

Range(ActiveCell, "p13").Select

With Selection

.Locked = True
End With




Range("a1").Select


ActiveSheet.Protect userinterfaceonly:=True


ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = False

End Sub
```

Comment: Can you post the Macro VBA code

Comment: I just added the code to the original post.  Thank you

Comment: You should probably get rid of every reference to the `Activate` and `Select` methods, except for those that are unavoidable (e.g., to return the focus to the select cell at the end of run-time, etc.).  Otherwise, please post screenshot of your worksheet.

Comment: How do I post a screenshot here?

Comment: Not sure about this, but isn't a template better than making the result with a macro?
Where is your "ebitda" phrase supposed to appear? I'm trying to duplicate the problem, but so far it's working for me: I get A1 selected at the end.

Comment: A template would be better but I'm running it out of a financial program that only stores macros, not templates.  ebitda appears in cell a102

Comment: Your post made me wonder if I could recreate the problem so I just ran the macro outside of the financial system and it worked as expected so maybe this is not solvable on this forum.

Answer (score 1):

```
Range("a1").Select

ActiveSheet.Protect userinterfaceonly:=True
```

I suspect that A1 is a locked cell, so that when you protect the worksheet it will jump to the nearest available cell that is not locked (assuming the option to allow selecting of locked cells was not checked from the last use).

Comment: A1 is not locked.  Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If your macro is jumping between the sheets, it might operate on the wrong one when selecting.
Try changing your select to:

```
Worksheets("sheetname").Range("A1").Select
```

Comment: I added this code to the end but unfortunately it still selected A8. And I'm only using one sheet.  Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You should start by getting rid of all of the .select statements (or as much as you can).  I know this isn't an explicit answer, but it's way to much to put in to a comment.  I do believe that getting rid of the .Select in your code will address the issue...but it's going to be a bit of work to sort it all out.  Nonetheless, here is a start for you:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Macro1()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
'
    Rows("6:6").Insert Shift:=xlDown
    Range("B7:O8").ClearContents

    With Range("B6:H8").Borders
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Weight = xlMedium
        .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    End With
    With Range("B6:H6").Borders
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Weight = xlMedium
        .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    End With

    With Range("B7:B8,E7:E8").Borders
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Weight = xlMedium
        .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    End With


    With Range("C7:C8,F7:F8").Borders
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Weight = xlMedium
        .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    End With

    With Range("D7:E7,G7:H7").Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Weight = xlMedium
        .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    End With

    With Range("B6").Font
        .Size = 14
    End With
    Range("B6").FormulaR1C1 = "Current Period"
    Range("B6:H6").HorizontalAlignment = xlCenterAcrossSelection

    Range("B8").FormulaR1C1 = "Actual"
    Range("B8").HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter


    With Range("B8").Font
        .Name = "Helvetica"
        .Size = 12
    End With

    With Range("C8").Font
        .Name = "Helvetica"
        .Size = 12
    End With

    Range("C8").HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter

    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Budget"
    Rows("8:8").Select
    With Selection
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter

    End With
    Range("D8").FormulaR1C1 = "$"
    Range("E8").FormulaR1C1 = "%"

    With Range("D7:E8").Font
        .Name = "Helvetica"
        .Size = 10
    End With

    With Range("F8").Font
        .Name = "Helvetica"
        .Size = 12
    End With

    Range("F8").FormulaR1C1 = "Last Year"
        Range("G8").FormulaR1C1 = "$"
    With Range("G7:H8").Font
        .Name = "Helvetica"
        .Size = 10
    End With

    Range("H8").FormulaR1C1 = "%"
    Range("D7").FormulaR1C1 = "B/(W) Than Budget"
    Range("D7:E7").HorizontalAlignment = xlCenterAcrossSelection


    Range("G7:H7").HorizontalAlignment = xlCenterAcrossSelection

    Range("G7").FormulaR1C1 = "B/(W) Than Last Year"
    Range("B6:H8").Copy Range("I6")
    Range("I6").FormulaR1C1 = "Year To Date"
    With Rows("1:4").Font
        .Size = 14
    End With

    With Rows("9:138").Font
        .Size = 10
    End With

    Rows("125:125").ClearContents
    Rows("133:133").ClearContents
    Range("B:D,F:G,I:K,M1,M:N").ColumnWidth = 15
    Range("E:E,h:h,l:l,o:o").ColumnWidth = 12
    Range("A:A").ColumnWidth = 40
    With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
        .PrintTitleRows = "$1:$8"
    End With


Rows("6:12").Insert Shift:=xlDown

Columns("i:i").Insert Shift:=xlRight

Range("g14:i14").HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft


Range("g14:h14").HorizontalAlignment = xlCenterAcrossSelection

Range("b13:i13").HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft

Range("b13:h13").HorizontalAlignment = xlCenterAcrossSelection


Range("k16:k200").Copy
Range("i16:i200").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats

Range("i:i,q:q").ColumnWidth = 38
Range("i:i,q:q").WrapText = True



Range("i13").Borders(xlEdgeTop).LineStyle = xlNone
Range("i13").Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = xlNone


With Range("i16").Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Weight = xlHairline
        .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    End With

With Range("i17").Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Weight = xlHairline
        .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    End With

Range("i17").Copy Range("i17:i200", "q16:q200")
    With Range("i14").Borders(xlEdgeTop)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Weight = xlMedium
        .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    End With

Range("i14").FormulaR1C1 = "Describe Variance"

Range("i14").HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter

Range("i14").Offset(1, 0).FormulaR1C1 = "to CP Budget"

Range("i14").Offset(1, 0).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter

Range("i14:i15").Copy
Range("q14:q15").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats


With Range("q14").Borders(xlEdgeTop)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Weight = xlMedium
        .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
End With
Range("q14").FormulaR1C1 = "Describe Variance"
Range("q14").HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter

Range("q14").Offset(1, 0).FormulaR1C1 = "to YTD Budget"

Range("q14").Offset(1, 0).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter



'''''''''''
'  Stopped here
'''''''''''


Cells.Find("ebitda", lookat:=xlWhole).Select
Selection.Offset(2, 0).Select
Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.Offset(200, 0)).Select
Selection.EntireRow.Delete

Cells.Find("ebitda", lookat:=xlWhole).Select
Selection.Offset(3, 0).Select
ActiveCell = "Explanation of EBITDA Variance to Budget (Only required if variance exceeded the acceptable range for your group)"
Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.Offset(0, 16)).Select

With Selection.Font
        .Size = 14
        .Bold = True
    End With
With Selection
.HorizontalAlignment = xlCenterAcrossSelection
End With

Selection.Offset(1, 0).Select
Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.Offset(0, 16)).Select
Selection.Merge
Selection.RowHeight = 50
With Selection.Font
        .Size = 10
         .Bold = True
End With


    With Selection
.HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
.VerticalAlignment = xlTop
.WrapText = True
End With

 With Selection.Borders
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Weight = xlMedium
        .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
 End With

Range("a1:q11").Select
With Selection
.HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
End With

With Selection
.HorizontalAlignment = xlCenterAcrossSelection
End With


Range("a6").Select
ActiveCell = "Publisher's Summary"
With Selection.Font
        .Size = 14
    End With
Range("a9").Select
ActiveCell = "Market Outlook"
With Selection.Font
        .Size = 14
    End With



Rows("10:10").Select
Selection.RowHeight = 70
Range("a10:q10").Select
Selection.Merge
 With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeLeft)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Weight = xlMedium
        .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeTop)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Weight = xlMedium
        .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Weight = xlMedium
        .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeRight)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Weight = xlMedium
        .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    End With
        With Selection
.HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
.VerticalAlignment = xlTop
.WrapText = True
End With

    With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
        .RightHeader = "&9Page &P of &N"
        .LeftMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.25)
        .RightMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.25)
        .TopMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.25)
        .BottomMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.25)
        .HeaderMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.1)
        .FooterMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.15)
        .CenterHorizontally = True
        .Orientation = xlLandscape
        .FitToPagesWide = 1
          .FitToPagesTall = 2
        .Zoom = False
    End With


    ActiveWindow.Zoom = 70


Rows("7:7").Select
Selection.RowHeight = 180
Range("a7:q7").Select
Selection.Merge
 With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeLeft)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Weight = xlMedium
        .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeTop)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Weight = xlMedium
        .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Weight = xlMedium
        .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeRight)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Weight = xlMedium
        .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    End With
    With Selection
.HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
.VerticalAlignment = xlTop
.WrapText = True
End With


Cells.Select

With Selection

.Locked = False
End With

Cells.Find("ebitda", lookat:=xlWhole).Select
Selection.Offset(1, 1).Select

Range(ActiveCell, "h13").Select

With Selection

.Locked = True
End With

Cells.Find("ebitda", lookat:=xlWhole).Select
Selection.Offset(1, 9).Select

Range(ActiveCell, "p13").Select

With Selection

.Locked = True
End With




Range("a1").Select


ActiveSheet.Protect userinterfaceonly:=True


ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = False

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

You'll find that your macro will run a lot faster and be much, much easier to debug. I'd start there.  Hopefully you'll be able to take the code I've posted above and finish modifying your code, I put in a comment block where I stopped.  Once you've done that, you may notice that the problem goes away entirely (since you're not selecting anything to start).  But even if you still have the problem, it will be much easier to sort out.

That's my answer at least and I hope it helps you go down the right path!

Comment: Thanks, I appricate the advice.  I'll give that a shot and try to write code in this manner going forward.  I'm fairly new to VBA and taught myself using this and other similar forums.

Comment: @user2638493 No problem...we all start somewhere.  From your comments in your original post, it appears that something else is going on (like the source system is doing something wonky).  Is there any other code in the workbook?

Comment: I agree, it seems to be the system not the actual macro.  What's strange is I've written dozens of similar macros without having this issue.  I don't see any other code but somehow the system triggers the macro to run when the report is exported.  I think I'll check in with their support although they don't seem to be very well versed in how macros work.  i'm going to run it without some elements of the macro to try to determine the root cause.

Comment: @user2638493 there is nothing in your macro to select A8, so the problem isn't your code.

Comment: Yep, definitely the source system, sorry to waste everyone's time but thanks for the help!